# Print to java GUI with for loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

Okay so i am making a program that requires me to print variables to the graphical interface. As i have no idea how many variables there will be i would like to use a for loop. The problem is when i do this the previous text i have printed goes away. Even if i print the text on different areas of the GUI. How could i print for example `1 2 3 4 5` twenty pixels apart from each number with JLabel and have all numbers stay on the GUI?

This is what i have come up with so far:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Email Sender");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setOpaque(true);
contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
frame.setSize(100, 60);
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setVisible(true);

int a[]=new int[5];
a[0]=10;
a[1]=20;
a[2]=70;
a[3]=40;
a[4]=50;
JLabel num = new Jlabel;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    num.setText((String.valueOf(a[i]));
    num.setLocation(20*i, 20);
    contentPane.add(num);

}
```

Comment: Side tip: Check out [Array Literals](http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/java/java-array-literals.php) when creating arrays known at compile time. It's just nicer syntax.

Comment: Call `setVisible` on the frame AFTER you've added everything

Answer (score 1):

So, there are at least three basic problems...

## One...

You only have one component, so when you do something like this...

```
JLabel num = new JLabel();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    num.setText((String.valueOf(a[i]));
    num.setLocation(20*i, 20);
    contentPane.add(num);

}
```

All you're doing is setting the properties of an already existing component and trying to add to a container it already resides in, so there is only ever one component.

## Two

You never set the size of the `JLabel`, and since you've decided to use a `null` layout, you become responsible for doing this

## Three

You call `setVisible` on the frame before the UI is finished been setup.  While you can do this, it's easier to establish the UI before showing the frame as it reduces other issues.  If you want to add components to the frame in a dynamic manner, you will need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you've added them to

## Example...

Now, taking all that into account, you could do something more like this...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

                int a[] = new int[5];
                a[0] = 10;
                a[1] = 20;
                a[2] = 70;
                a[3] = 40;
                a[4] = 50;
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    JLabel num = new JLabel((String.valueOf(a[i])));
                    num.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0));
                    contentPane.add(num);
                }
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

*nb: I don't like, nor do I condone, the use of `null` layouts, for all the times people "think" they need them, they don't*

If you are listing a variable number of components, you might find using a `JList` more practical, as it supports vertical and horizontal wrapping and scrolling